# How can I connect my firebase to different files and display all documents?

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic4

Connected Firebase already but not able to use it in different files. Need to know how I can access that and display firebase content.

file system:
src -> app -> home

app module.ts :

```
export class AppModule {}
var config = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyBvJ0ZWfd2GcIpKgdcIaZKJ6ohLW_E7DOs",
  authDomain: "fir-storage-login.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://fir-storage-login.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "firebase-storage-login",
  storageBucket: "firebase-storage-login.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "803036592201"
};
var app = firebase.initializeApp(config);
var database = firebase.database(app);
```

home.page.html

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getStations($event)"></ion-searchbar>
        <ion-list>
          <ion-item *ngFor="let station of stations">
              {{ station }}
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
```

home.page.ts

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { AppModule } from '../app.module';

states: Array<any>;

initializeStates(){  
return firebase.database().ref('States').once('value').then(snapshot =`> 
snapshot.val());{
this.states }
```

Comment: Please share with us what you have tried and the error or unexpected behavior that you get and what you expect to happen. [This article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) might help you rephrasing your question so that people can help you better.

Comment: your code at the end of `home.page.ts` just seems to go off into a mess - did you paste it in wrong?